# Linkbutton postback-url changes after second time of sorting/paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have a asp.net page which has been url rewritten and when im sorting my gridview or paging it via my custom pager it works.

This works fine for first postback to the using the update panel,  but 2nd
postback the url has changed to the wrong url.   When u view source the form
action= is still point to correct url, but updatepanel / datagrid is ignoring
this and using some other url.

why and how can i ensure this url is always the rewritten version used for
updatepanel postbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
}
```